# Travis CI fails to parse .travis.yml

Tags: yaml, travis-ci

I have this `travis.yml` which travis-ci.org complains it can't parse.

```
language: rust
rust:
  - 1.31.0
  - stable
  - beta
  - nightly
matrix:
  allow_failures:
    - rust: nightly
sudo: false
before_script:
  - rustup component add rustfmt
  - rustup target add thumbv7em-none-eabihf     # Any target that does not have a standard library will do
script:
  - cargo fmt --all -- --check
  - (rustup component add clippy && cargo clippy --all -- -D clippy::all) || true
  - cargo build
  - cargo test
  - cargo build --no-default-features --features alloc --target thumbv7em-none-eabihf # Test we can build a platform that does not have std.
  - cargo test --no-default-features --lib --tests # Run no_std tests
  - [[ $TRAVIS_RUST_VERSION != "1.31.0" ]] && cargo build --no-default-features --features alloc
  - cargo build --features unsealed_read_write # The crate should still build when the unsealed_read_write feature is enabled.
  - cargo build --no-default-features --features unsealed_read_write # The crate should still build when the unsealed_read_write feature is enabled and std disabled.
```

This file belongs to https://github.com/pyfisch/cbor and the line that apparently causes the parsing failure is `- [[ $TRAVIS_RUST_VERSION != "1.31.0" ]] && cargo build --no-default-features --features alloc`.

[Online Travis.yml validation](http://lint.travis-ci.org/) is less than helpful (deprecated and removed without a replacement).

What changes are needed so Travis does build again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `[` character is special in YAML, like a few others.
If your string starts with it, you need to quote it.

I recommend using a block scalar for longer strings. You can either use a literal block scalar, which will be taken as it is:

```
- |
  [[ $TRAVIS_RUST_VERSION != "1.31.0" ]] && cargo build --no-default-features --features alloc
```

or a folded block scalar which allows you to split the line over multiple lines. It will be folded together with spaces:

```
- >
  [[ $TRAVIS_RUST_VERSION != "1.31.0" ]]
  && cargo build --no-default-features --features alloc
```

If you want to know more about quoting strings in YAML, I can recommend [my article on this](http://blogs.perl.org/users/tinita/2018/03/strings-in-yaml---to-quote-or-not-to-quote.html).